# How can I make my program compile using annotations with eclipse and working with java?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, maven

Ive been trying to compile my program, at my other machine (windows) works perfectly, at this one , fresh installed (debian) is not working and I am seeing an exception never saw before...

Basically is like this:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project other: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/juan/workspace/orden/src/main/java/com/myrepo/other/repository/TableRepository.java:[9,1] annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
[ERROR] (use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)
[ERROR] @Transactional
```

and I get this at every trable mapped at my repository.

I have installed java jdk 1.6, and I tried to create my `JAVA_HOME`, I used this info http://www.jusuchyne.com/codingforme/linux/set-java_home-environment-variable-linux/

when I make echo $JAVA_HOME works , if i close the shell I have to make again 
`source ~/.bash_profile`
to get the result again...

I have set my maven path and all good, but I dont know why I keep getting this, I am compiling with jdk1.6 on eclipse (the one is installed)

at my `~/.bash_profile` I have this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-amd64/bin
```

any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems you forget to set the -source and -target properties. (You might be using different mavens on the computers.) See also: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: you know which dependency should I modify? I have many from a pom I didnt do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Java 1.5 or higher is not enough, you also need to tell Maven the Java compatibility level.

Try adding the following to your POM:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```